# Approximating a modified Gaussian integral by considering tail-end behavior

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, gaussian-integral, distribution-tails

I am considering calculating the following definite integral. The limits of integration are positive and $c > 0$. One can see that the integrand is bounded above by the Gaussian in the numerator and so the integral should converge

$$
\int_{a}^b \frac{e^{-cx^2}}{x+1}dx
$$

Suppose the limits of integrations are several standard deviations (of $e^{-cx^2}$) away. Then it makes sense to approximate $e^{-cx^2}$ with some function that models the Gaussian's end behaviors quite well. The integral then seems tractable to me. For instance, if the numerator was approximately $1/cx$, then I could use partial fraction decomposition and natural logarithms.

**What is the functional form of the Gaussian $e^{-cx^2}$ at its tails?**

Comment: As an infinite series probably

Comment: See [Goodwin Staton integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodwin–Staton_integral) for definite integral.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Thank you for the link

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠. Thanks for the link. Do you know how to write $\large\color{red}{\text{csgn}}$ using Mathematica ? Cheers :-)